# TFS 2013 not working with IIS reverse proxy

Tags: tfs

I am trying to use an IIS reverse proxy to make my TFS server accessible to a different group of users on the network.

I have anonymous authentication turned on on the reverse proxy server (URL Rewrite and ARR).  Whenever I try to connect to the TFS server I get a 401, and typing the password correctly in doesn't work.

I have tried both of these Rewrite URLs:

```
http://192.168.1.85:8080/{R:0}
http://192.168.1.85:8080/{R:1}
```

Both are producing the 401, though.  I have tried turning Windows Authentication and Basic Authentication on and off.  Neither of those work, either.  TFS is installed with a default configuration.

Any ideas?  I know folks are doing this to expose TFS, so hopefully there is an easy way to get it to work.

Comment: You need to turn on Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically TFS would be installed in a virtual directory "tfs" at port 8080. Therefore if you have a typical IIS setup, you should change your rewrite URL from:

```
http://192.168.1.85:8080/{R:0}
```

to

```
http://192.168.1.85:8080/tfs/
```

Chances are though the above by itself won't be enough since all of your relative links will be broken therefore to fix this, what I recommend is this for your match url patten:

```
^(tfs/)?(.*)?
```

and then this for your rewrite pattern:

```
http://192.168.1.85:8080/tfs/{R:2}
```

I hope this helps.